# what are the differences between Google compute engine and Google container engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I was wondering what are the differences between Container Engine & Compute Engine?

If I have a Jax~rs application on host which done by Groovy and Jetty, and planning to to migrate to Google cloud platform ,shoud I start for Google container or google compute?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Google Compute Engine**
It is based on [Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).

**Google Container Engine**
It is based on [Docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker).

Compute engine will be easy as working on linux machine but for container you need to know [how docker works](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/) and there are some [use cases for docker](https://www.docker.com/use-cases).

You should start with Google Compute but if you are interested in experiments then go with Container engine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, If my purpose is only want a hosting service doesn't matter VM or docker. I just want it able to support **Jetty server**, **Groovy** technology, **maven/gradle** on SSH as I don't want to modify my architecture again. Should I go for Compute Engine?

Comment: Yes that is perfectly fine with  Google compute.

Comment: Can you run docker on your compute engine server?  If so, why wouldn't you just do that instead of using container engine?

Comment: Because GKE (container engine) abstracts away managing images, gives you private docker image storage. It has a Kubernetes installed which helps to manage the containers.

Container engine could be think of as running on top of compute engine with some extra tweeks.

Comment: Is that correct that Google Container Engine is a set of physical servers running Kuberentes that manages Docker containers, and users rent/buy these containers?